# CF, OF in flag register during data overflow

Tags: assembly, x86, integer-overflow, emu8086, eflags

With Intel x86 / emu8086 emulator, when there is an overflow of a byte with following values:

```
mov al,-128
sub al,128
```

How come the CF is 0, and OF is also 0? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

-128 and 128 are the same number in 8-bit (2's complement or unsigned).  i.e. the immediate for both instructions is `0x80`.

`x - x` = 0 with no carry (unsigned) or overflow (signed).

Comment: right, thanks. when I "sub al,128" the 128 here already overflows as -128 since al is initialized as signed byte.